convert complex list of combinations to Dataframe
I have created the following code that results in a list of combinations
experiment <- expand.grid(
  flavor=c("chocolate", "vanilla", "strawberry"), 
  price=c("$1.50", "$2.00", "$2.50"), 
  container=c("cone", "cup"), 
  topping=c("yes", "no"))

# Dividir el conjunto de datos en grupos de 3 filas
grupos <- split(experiment, rep(1:ceiling(nrow(experiment)/3), each=3, 
                                length.out=nrow(experiment)))

# Crear escenarios para cada grupo
escenarios <- lapply(grupos, function(grupo) {
  # Mostrar los objetos de cada grupo
  for (i in 1:nrow(grupo)) {
    cat("Objeto", i, ":\n")
    print(grupo[i, ])
    cat("\n")
  }
})

get the following list of objects
Objeto 1 :
     flavor price container topping
1 chocolate $1.50      cone     yes

Objeto 2 :
   flavor price container topping
2 vanilla $1.50      cone     yes

Objeto 3 :
      flavor price container topping
3 strawberry $1.50      cone     yes

Objeto 1 :
     flavor price container topping
4 chocolate $2.00      cone     yes

Objeto 2 :
   flavor price container topping
5 vanilla $2.00      cone     yes

Objeto 3 :
      flavor price container topping
6 strawberry $2.00      cone     yes

Objeto 1 :
     flavor price container topping
7 chocolate $2.50      cone     yes

Objeto 2 :
   flavor price container topping
8 vanilla $2.50      cone     yes

Objeto 3 :
      flavor price container topping
9 strawberry $2.50      cone     yes

Objeto 1 :
      flavor price container topping
10 chocolate $1.50       cup     yes

Objeto 2 :
    flavor price container topping
11 vanilla $1.50       cup     yes

Objeto 3 :
       flavor price container topping
12 strawberry $1.50       cup     yes

Objeto 1 :
      flavor price container topping
13 chocolate $2.00       cup     yes

Objeto 2 :
    flavor price container topping
14 vanilla $2.00       cup     yes

Objeto 3 :
       flavor price container topping
15 strawberry $2.00       cup     yes

Objeto 1 :
      flavor price container topping
16 chocolate $2.50       cup     yes

Objeto 2 :
    flavor price container topping
17 vanilla $2.50       cup     yes

Objeto 3 :
       flavor price container topping
18 strawberry $2.50       cup     yes

Objeto 1 :
      flavor price container topping
19 chocolate $1.50      cone      no

Objeto 2 :
    flavor price container topping
20 vanilla $1.50      cone      no

Objeto 3 :
       flavor price container topping
21 strawberry $1.50      cone      no

Objeto 1 :
      flavor price container topping
22 chocolate $2.00      cone      no

Objeto 2 :
    flavor price container topping
23 vanilla $2.00      cone      no

Objeto 3 :
       flavor price container topping
24 strawberry $2.00      cone      no

Objeto 1 :
      flavor price container topping
25 chocolate $2.50      cone      no

Objeto 2 :
    flavor price container topping
26 vanilla $2.50      cone      no

Objeto 3 :
       flavor price container topping
27 strawberry $2.50      cone      no

Objeto 1 :
      flavor price container topping
28 chocolate $1.50       cup      no

Objeto 2 :
    flavor price container topping
29 vanilla $1.50       cup      no

Objeto 3 :
       flavor price container topping
30 strawberry $1.50       cup      no

Objeto 1 :
      flavor price container topping
31 chocolate $2.00       cup      no

Objeto 2 :
    flavor price container topping
32 vanilla $2.00       cup      no

Objeto 3 :
       flavor price container topping
33 strawberry $2.00       cup      no

Objeto 1 :
      flavor price container topping
34 chocolate $2.50       cup      no

Objeto 2 :
    flavor price container topping
35 vanilla $2.50       cup      no

Objeto 3 :
       flavor price container topping
36 strawberry $2.50       cup      no

I would like to convert this into a data frame. I have tried the following code:
f <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, grupos))

getting an unwanted result

The way I would like to get it in a dataframe would be



Object 1
Object 2
Object 3




chocolate $1.50  cone  yes
vanilla $1.50       cone      yes
strawberry $1.50      cone     yes


Second
row




I tried code like I show below
# Crear un dataframe para almacenar los escenarios reconfigurados
df_escenarios <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3, nrow=length(escenarios)))
colnames(df_escenarios) <- c("Object 1", "Object 2", "Object 3")

# Llenar el dataframe con los escenarios
for (i in 1:length(escenarios)) {
  if (length(escenarios[[i]]) > 0) {  # Verificar que haya escenarios en el grupo
    df_escenarios[i, ] <- unlist(escenarios[[i]])
  } else {
    df_escenarios[i, ] <- NA  # Si no hay escenarios, llenar con NA
  }
}
# Imprimir el dataframe
print(df_escenarios)

but the attempt is empty
     Object 1 Object 2 Object 3
1        NA       NA       NA
2        NA       NA       NA
3        NA       NA       NA
4        NA       NA       NA
5        NA       NA       NA
6        NA       NA       NA
7        NA       NA       NA
8        NA       NA       NA
9        NA       NA       NA
10       NA       NA       NA
11       NA       NA       NA
12       NA       NA       NA 

Thank you in advance for your help

Your escenarios object is actually a list of NULLs values. You get nothing because the function inside your lapply does not return anything after the for loop.

 do.call(paste, experiment) |>
   matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0('Object',1:3))) |>
   data.frame()
                    Object1                Object2                   Object3
1  chocolate $1.50 cone yes vanilla $1.50 cone yes strawberry $1.50 cone yes
2  chocolate $2.00 cone yes vanilla $2.00 cone yes strawberry $2.00 cone yes
3  chocolate $2.50 cone yes vanilla $2.50 cone yes strawberry $2.50 cone yes
4   chocolate $1.50 cup yes  vanilla $1.50 cup yes  strawberry $1.50 cup yes
5   chocolate $2.00 cup yes  vanilla $2.00 cup yes  strawberry $2.00 cup yes
6   chocolate $2.50 cup yes  vanilla $2.50 cup yes  strawberry $2.50 cup yes
7   chocolate $1.50 cone no  vanilla $1.50 cone no  strawberry $1.50 cone no
8   chocolate $2.00 cone no  vanilla $2.00 cone no  strawberry $2.00 cone no
9   chocolate $2.50 cone no  vanilla $2.50 cone no  strawberry $2.50 cone no
10   chocolate $1.50 cup no   vanilla $1.50 cup no   strawberry $1.50 cup no
11   chocolate $2.00 cup no   vanilla $2.00 cup no   strawberry $2.00 cup no
12   chocolate $2.50 cup no   vanilla $2.50 cup no   strawberry $2.50 cup no


Other methods include:
data.frame(t(sapply(grupos, do.call, what = paste)))


invoke_map_df(\(...)data.frame(t(paste(...))), grupos)


map_df(grupos, ~data.frame(t(exec(paste, !!!.))))


I would never have thought of such a solution, thank you very much

You could paste the rows together. Maybe easier to split along interactions.
> split(experiment, with(experiment, interaction(price, container, topping))) |> 
+   lapply(Reduce, f=paste) |> do.call(what='rbind.data.frame') |> 
+   setNames(paste('Object_', seq_along(unique(experiment$flavor))))
                   Object_1               Object_2                  Object_3
1  chocolate $1.50 cone yes vanilla $1.50 cone yes strawberry $1.50 cone yes
2  chocolate $2.00 cone yes vanilla $2.00 cone yes strawberry $2.00 cone yes
3  chocolate $2.50 cone yes vanilla $2.50 cone yes strawberry $2.50 cone yes
4   chocolate $1.50 cup yes  vanilla $1.50 cup yes  strawberry $1.50 cup yes
5   chocolate $2.00 cup yes  vanilla $2.00 cup yes  strawberry $2.00 cup yes
6   chocolate $2.50 cup yes  vanilla $2.50 cup yes  strawberry $2.50 cup yes
7   chocolate $1.50 cone no  vanilla $1.50 cone no  strawberry $1.50 cone no
8   chocolate $2.00 cone no  vanilla $2.00 cone no  strawberry $2.00 cone no
9   chocolate $2.50 cone no  vanilla $2.50 cone no  strawberry $2.50 cone no
10   chocolate $1.50 cup no   vanilla $1.50 cup no   strawberry $1.50 cup no
11   chocolate $2.00 cup no   vanilla $2.00 cup no   strawberry $2.00 cup no
12   chocolate $2.50 cup no   vanilla $2.50 cup no   strawberry $2.50 cup no

If you want stick to your method, just use
> grupos |> 
+   lapply(Reduce, f=paste) |> do.call(what='rbind.data.frame') |> 
+   setNames(paste('Object_', seq_along(unique(experiment$flavor))))


One solution using tidyverse:
mutate(experiment, 
       row=rep(1:12, each=3),
       group=rep(1:3, times=12),
       Object=paste(flavor, price, container, topping), .keep="none") %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from="group",
              values_from="Object",
              names_prefix="Object")
___
# A tibble: 12 × 4
     row Object1                  Object2                Object3                  
   <int> <chr>                    <chr>                  <chr>                    
 1     1 chocolate $1.50 cone yes vanilla $1.50 cone yes strawberry $1.50 cone yes
 2     2 chocolate $2.00 cone yes vanilla $2.00 cone yes strawberry $2.00 cone yes
 3     3 chocolate $2.50 cone yes vanilla $2.50 cone yes strawberry $2.50 cone yes
 4     4 chocolate $1.50 cup yes  vanilla $1.50 cup yes  strawberry $1.50 cup yes 
 5     5 chocolate $2.00 cup yes  vanilla $2.00 cup yes  strawberry $2.00 cup yes 
 6     6 chocolate $2.50 cup yes  vanilla $2.50 cup yes  strawberry $2.50 cup yes 
 7     7 chocolate $1.50 cone no  vanilla $1.50 cone no  strawberry $1.50 cone no 
 8     8 chocolate $2.00 cone no  vanilla $2.00 cone no  strawberry $2.00 cone no 
 9     9 chocolate $2.50 cone no  vanilla $2.50 cone no  strawberry $2.50 cone no 
10    10 chocolate $1.50 cup no   vanilla $1.50 cup no   strawberry $1.50 cup no  
11    11 chocolate $2.00 cup no   vanilla $2.00 cup no   strawberry $2.00 cup no  
12    12 chocolate $2.50 cup no   vanilla $2.50 cup no   strawberry $2.50 cup no 


Why do you group_by before pivoting? that does not do anything.
